# How to build and configure .net assembly so it ignores version of referenced DLL at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, version

I am building a DLL in C# that references another DLL. I don't want the DLL that I am building to care about which version of the referenced DLL is on the customer's computer at runtime (note: I do not ship the referenced DLL to them, only the one that I build). It turns out that they have a newer version of the referenced DLL on their machine and when they tried to execute the code in my DLL they got the following error:

*Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Could not loadfile or assembly ', Version=, Culture=neutral*

In case it helps to know, the Specific Version property on the referenced DLL is set to False in my Visual Studio. How can I build my DLLs so that it won't complain about the version of the referenced DLL that the customer has deployed on their machine?

Comment: Dll is never vb or c#. C# - project. DLL=IL

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong terminology then but I am definitely writing the code in C#, I have the project's output type set to Class Library, and the result of building the project is a .dll file.

Comment: Say anything you want, but there is no c# in dll

Comment: I'm not saying that the DLL contains C# code, I'm saying that the project is written in C# and compiles into a DLL.

Comment: Don't worry, we understand what you mean. But your header saying *"Build C# DLL..."*

Comment: I fixed your header and I remind you to check my answer. It has link to Microsof reference of how to do what you need. And see my update

Answer (score 1):

When you build an assembly the dll version of referenced assembly is written into your assembly. Generally, and without any configuration, it will have no troubles if you replace originally referenced assembly with the one of higher version, where only first 3 numbers matter. `1.1.1.x` - `x` doesn't matter. And as long as "replacement assembly" contains API that your code may call. It seems that you have exactly that issue - a different constructor in the version you using that wasn't present in original assembly.

For making your assembly work with various versions of referenced dlls you can try to tweak `app.config` to set version range for this dll. [Read about redirecting assembly version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The original version number I built against is 8.4.0.7 and the version on the customer's system is 8.5.0.12. According to the documentation the constructors are all the same so is there something else that could be causing the issue? When doing the redirect, it requires me to specify a "newVersion" value which, according to the documentation, doesn't look like it can contain a range (unlike the "oldVersion" value). Doesn't this mean that it will still only look for a particular version of the DLL?

Comment: I really not sure what `newVersion` does. But I had this issue yesterday when in .config file I had max range of versions lesser than one I wanted to use. I incremented it and it worked. It would be interesting to see which assembly is actually loaded - `appdomain.currentdomain.getassemblies...` You may loading something else entirely because there can be something in GAC which precedes local folder

Comment: In that situation what did you put in for newVersion? It says it is a required field. Also, is it mandatory to put the publicKeyToken in the assembly information?

Comment: @Hmmmmm In fact I did entered the version that I was about to use. I really don't know about public key but usually same assembly carries over same key.